# Checkout broken after when payment information clicks

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, ce-1.7.0.2

Checkout broken after when payment information continue button clicks not working in Magento 1.7.0.2 the button is not clickable please anyone who came across this error or problem please give a solution much appreciated

Comment: Are you able to inspect the page? are there any console errors? Does the button have the `disabled` attribute?

Comment: No any error, it worked yesterday but now when i go to place a order i can access till the payment information step but after i can not press continue button it does't work click like clickable, missing orders please help me to solve this losing money users get disappointment  please

Comment: Share website link, have you applied any security patches or installed nay plugin recently

Comment: Thanks for the response friend, its sounds good, Not really i did not installed any plugin it suddenly happened, link has given below any solution for this much appreciated (www.mumzcare.com)

Comment: Is that anything wrong with the payment gateway?